# How is inverse ARP configured in frame relay?

Tags: cisco, wan, frame-relay

I've tried to find an explanation online that just simply tells me how inverse ARP is configured, and I can't seem to find a straight answer for it.

Let's use the below diagram as an example.

[image]

As you can see, I've configured this as an MP frame relay all in the subnet. Now I could quite easily link all of these together by creating static maps. That's not the issue.

What I'd really like to know is what configuration needs to take place in order for inverse ARP to work between the routers? My guess would be to place routes on the frame relay switch from one DLCI to an outgoing interface, but how does the frame relay switch know where the DLCI is coming from? Does it need to still be mapped somewhere else, so there's communication between the routers and frame relay switch? Otherwise it just seems like a free for all.

Any help would be appreciated, as I'd really like clarity on this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marking as answered as this was discovered a long time ago through numerous lab setups and research.